# Split nested list in a column pandas

Tags: pandas, list, nested

My data 
Col 1                 Col2
[[1,2,4],[1,2,5]]      10

I need to  seperate the nested list in column 1 to form as a seperate column in pandas dataframe

My output

Col 1      Col2        Col3

[1,2,4]   [1,2,5]       10

Comment: Try solution from dupe, if still problem let me know

Comment: Hi that solution doesnt work if i have some other columns in addition to the nested lists

Comment: Do you need `df = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Col1').tolist(), index=df.index).join(df)` ?